# always display select option on top of select dropdown list in react js antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

in select dropdown menu I have added default option value "--select--". Currently it is displaying at the bottom of the select list. I wanted to display it on top of the list. Please help how I can achieve this.

In sandbox I added code. please find link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-albattani-xdeud?file=/src/App.js

component :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Form, Select } from "antd";
import CollegeList from "./CollegeList";

const { Option } = Select;

const App = () => {
  const [collegesList, setCollegesList] = React.useState(CollegeList);
  const [collegesSelectedList, setCollegesSelectedList] = React.useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const defaultState = {
      name: "--select--"
    };
    setCollegesList([...collegesList, defaultState]);
    console.log("initial load");
  }, []);

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
  };

  return (
    <Form name="validate_other" onFinish={onFinish}>
      <Form.Item name="select" label="Select">
        <Select
          placeholder="Please select a country"
          onChange={(college) => {
            setCollegesSelectedList([
              ...collegesSelectedList,
              collegesList[college].name
            ]);
          }}
        >
          {Object.keys(collegesList).map((college) => (
            <Option value={college}>{collegesList[college].name}</Option>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

currently it display bottom of the dropdown list.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your setCollegesList as below :

```
    setCollegesList([defaultState, ...collegesList]);
       console.log("initial load");
  }, []);
```

And it will work I have updated codesandbox here for your reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-firefly-6mqip?file=/src/App.js